# How to compile a c program with some user inputs in Node.js app using child_process.exec(command[, options][, callback])

Tags: node.js

I am making a Node.js app to compile and execute various c/c++ programs.

I am using child_process.exec(command[, options][, callback]) to run the commands "gcc test.c" to compile a c code written in test.c which takes user input and displays the output and "./a.out" to execute the file.

I can't find a way to execute it with user inputs, I only want to use child_process.exec() because I can handle infinite loops using options.timeout.

I have tried to compile and execute a c program without user inputs and it works fine.

I am using:

- Ubuntu 19.10
- Node.js v12.11.1.
- gcc (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008

test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("n = %d\n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

node.js app

```js
const cp = require("child_process");

const exec_options = {
    cwd : "/home/hardik/Desktop" ,
    timeout : 1000 ,
    killSignal : "SIGTERM"
};

cp.exec("gcc test.c",exec_options,(error,stdout,stderr) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else if(stderr) { 
        console.log(stderr);
    }
    else {
        cp.exec("./a.out",exec_options,(error,stdout,stderr) => {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else if(stderr) {
                console.log(stderr);
            }
            else {
                console.log("output : "+stdout);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `.exec()` to `.spawn()` first. It's because `.exec()` buffers the output while the `.spawn()` streams it so it's more suitable for the *interactive* program. Another thing is to add `{ stdio: 'inherit' }` to your `exec_options`. Additionally, if it's running on Windows, there's another parameter to add: `{ shell: true }`. To sum up, it should look something like this:

```
const isWindows = process.platform === 'win32';
const exec_options = {
    cwd : "/home/hardik/Desktop" ,
    timeout : 1000 ,
    killSignal : "SIGTERM",
    stdio: 'inherit',
    ...(isWindows && { shell: true })
};

const run = cp.spawn("./a.out", [], exec_options);

run.on('error', console.error);
```